# How to get value of onclick using xpath?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have this piece of Html:

```html
<tr class="selectable" onclick="PesquisarProntuarioView.EditarProntuario('108077098085')">
```

I would like to get what is inside onclick, i was looking for a command which would give me:

```html
"PesquisarProntuarioView.EditarProntuario('01048108077098085')"
```

I already have tried several commands like this one:

```html
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/tr/@onlick=PesquisarProntuarioView.EditarProntuario(*)")

driver.get(element)
```

However still no clue, Could someone please help me with the respective command in Selenium/Python?

Answer (score 5):

Locate the element and use [`get_attribute()` method](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/tr")
print(element.get_attribute("onclick"))
```

If there are multiple elements you need to extract `onclick` from, use `find_elements_*` and call `get_attribute()` for every element found:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a/tr"):
    print(element.get_attribute("onclick"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Alexcxe and Kiril! - but, unfortunately still not working - a image here - http://i.imgur.com/cqLkQ3h.png - i ve highlighted what im looking for

Answer (score 3):

I would slightly change the above solution to only select relevant elements in path `//a/tr` by providing part of the `onclick` attribute, like this:

```
onclickValue = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a/tr[contains(@onlick,'PesquisarProntuarioView.EditarProntuario')]").get_attribute("onclick")
```